# Failure expanding more than one listItems

Tags: android, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception

I actually have two `ExpandableListView` elements like this:

[image]

But I want to add more `ExpandableListView` elements in the near feature.

The problem is, that when I click on the second element a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` appears (the first one works great):

Here is the logcat:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at de.gestureanywhere.MyExpandableAdapter.getChildrenCount(MyExpandableAdapter.java:142)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.refreshExpGroupMetadataList(ExpandableListConnector.java:563)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.expandGroup(ExpandableListConnector.java:688)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:691)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:651)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3057)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$4.run(AbsListView.java:3799)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

These are the corresponding parts of my code:

```
private ArrayList< String > elternelemente = new ArrayList< String > ();
private ArrayList< Object > kindElemente = new ArrayList< Object > ();
```

...

```
ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = (ExpandableListView) findViewById ( android.R.id.list );

    // Zeilenabstand bestimmen
    liste_schritt1.setDividerHeight ( 10 );

    // Pfeil an der Seite rechts anzeigen lassen durch setGroupIndicator
    // liste_schritt1.setGroupIndicator ( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.expandiconempty) );
    liste_schritt1.setClickable ( true );

    elternElementTexte ();
    kindElementTexte ();

    MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter (elternelemente, kindElemente );


    adapter.setInflater ( ( LayoutInflater ) getSystemService ( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE ), this );
    liste_schritt1.setAdapter ( adapter );

    liste_schritt1.setOnChildClickListener ( liste_schritt1_Listener );
```

...

```
private void elternElementTexte () {

    elternelemente.add("Anwendung starten");
    elternelemente.add("Anwendung beenden");


}


private void kindElementTexte () {

    // TODO: Bildericons sollen angezeigt werden

    ActivityManager manager = ( ActivityManager ) this.getSystemService ( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );


    ArrayList< String > kinder = new ArrayList< String > ();


    final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager ();
    List< ApplicationInfo > packages = pm.getInstalledApplications ( PackageManager.GET_META_DATA );

    View inflate = getLayoutInflater(). inflate(R. layout. anwendung_starten_layout, null);

    CharSequence charsequence = null;

    for ( ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages ) {

        charsequence = pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo);

        kinder.add ( charsequence.toString() );
    }


    kindElemente.add ( kinder );

}
```

And this is my `MyExpandableAdapter` class:

```
public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


static Activity activity;
private ArrayList< Object > childtems;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ArrayList< String > elternElementeGlobal;

// enthält alle installierten Programme: [Package Access Helper, Kontakte, Telefon, Rechner,...]
private ArrayList< String > kindElementeGlobal;

// wird von GestureAnyWhere aufgerufen
public MyExpandableAdapter ( ArrayList< String > elternelemente, ArrayList< Object > kindelemente ) {

    this.elternElementeGlobal = elternelemente;
    this.childtems = kindelemente;
}

public void setInflater ( LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity ) {
    this.inflater = inflater;
    this.activity = activity;
}

@Override
// wird aufgerufen, wenn auf ein Elternelement geklickt wurde bzw. immer dann wenn die Liste gescrollt wird
public View getChildView ( int groupPosition, final int kindposition, boolean isLastChild, View layout_mit_Liste_View, ViewGroup parent ) {

    Log.d("groupPosition1", "groupPosition1 " + groupPosition);
    kindElementeGlobal = ( ArrayList< String > ) childtems.get ( groupPosition );

    // die groupPosition bestimmt möglicherweise die Position des Elternelementes (z.B. 0 für 1. geklicktes Elternelement)
    Log.d("groupPosition", "groupPosition " + groupPosition);

    // enthält alle installierten Programme: [Package Access Helper, Kontakte, Telefon, Rechner,...]
    Log.d("kindElementeGlobal", "kindElementeGlobal " + kindElementeGlobal);

    TextView textView = null;


    if ( layout_mit_Liste_View == null ) {
        // referenziert auf das Layout, welches die ExpandableListView enthält
        layout_mit_Liste_View = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.anwendung_starten_layout, null );
    }

    // setzt die Texte jeder einzelnen Zeile der ExpandableListView
    textView = ( TextView ) layout_mit_Liste_View.findViewById ( R.id.text_zeile_Liste);
    textView.setText(kindElementeGlobal.get(kindposition));

    // die kindposition bestimmt die Position der Kindelemente
    Log.d("kindposition", "kindposition " + kindposition);

    final TextView finalTextView = textView;

    // wenn auf eine Zeile der ExpandableListView geklickt wurde
    layout_mit_Liste_View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // ermittle den Text einer Zeile, um auf der nächsten Activity der Applikationsname als Überschrift anzuzeigen
            final String applikationsname = finalTextView.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(activity, applikationsname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // sobald auf ein Item geklickt wurde
            Intent itemClicked = new Intent(activity, ItemClicked.class);

            // muss definiert sein, da es nicht innerhalb einer von Activity abgeleiteten Klasse aufgerufen wird
            itemClicked.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);

            // Teile dem Intent den Applikationsnamen mit, um auf der nächsten Activity der Applikationsname als Überschrift anzuzeigen
            itemClicked.putExtra("applikationsname", applikationsname);

            // muss so definiert sein, da nicht innerhalb einer Activity aufgerufen
            activity.getApplication().startActivity(itemClicked);
        }
    });

    return layout_mit_Liste_View;
}

@Override
// erhält den Namen der Elternelemente (z.B. groupPosition 0: Anwendung starten)
public View getGroupView ( int groupPosition, boolean ausgeklappt, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {

    if ( convertView == null ) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.row, null );
    }

    String text = elternElementeGlobal.get(groupPosition);
    Log.d("text", "text " + text);

    ( ( CheckedTextView ) convertView ).setText(text);
    ( ( CheckedTextView ) convertView ).setChecked(ausgeklappt);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Object getChild ( int groupPosition, int childPosition )
{
    Log.d("in getChild", "in getChild " + groupPosition + "|" + childPosition);
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId ( int groupPosition, int childPosition ) {

    Log.d("in getChildID", "in getChildID " + groupPosition + "|" + childPosition);
    return 0;
}

@Override
// wird aufgerufen, wenn ein Elternteil ausgeklappt wird
public int getChildrenCount ( int groupPosition ) {
   // int size = ( ( ArrayList< String > ) childtems.get ( groupPosition ) ).size ();

    //Log.d("size", "size " + size); // 105
    Log.d("in getChildrenCount", "getChildrenCount " + groupPosition);

    // return 210;
    // die Anzahl muss richtig sein, da es ansonsten zu einem IndexOutOfBoundsException Error
    // 105, da 105 installierte Programme (105 Kindelemente)
     return ( ( ArrayList< String > ) childtems.get ( groupPosition ) ).size ();
    // return 211;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup ( int groupPosition ) {

    Log.d("in getGroup", "in getGroup " + groupPosition);
    return null;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you update items in your adapter call: `notifyDataSetChanged()` on adapter.

Comment: ok thx for your answer. But when I start my application and click on the second listView I always get the IndexOutOfBoundsException. The first ListView works always. I have only used one Adapter for both listViews. Do I have to use a second adapter or how shall I change the code for working?

Comment: @user3603935 In my opinion there are many things that can go wrong here. You should properly override `getChild()` and `getGroup()` and in your `getGroupView()` and `getChildView()` call `getChild()` and `getGroup()`   respectively instead of directly calling your `ArrayList`. The problem may lie here. If you wish - do that and update the code in question so that we can have a further look.

Comment: Do you mean just adding getChild() in getChildView() and  getGroup() in getGroupView() without changing the other code? This result is, that the app won't crash anymore, but the second list doesn't expand

Comment: Could you Please provide me a possible solution? Thanks

Comment: @user3603935 you also need to use getChild() and getGroup() in your getChildView() and getGroupView(). Here is proper implementation of getChild() and getGroup() along with count:
http://pastebin.com/SHhjXu11